# Word that is the string of characters/phonemes that compose a 'word'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, objects, homonyms

The string "cool" represents several 'words'/linguistic meanings: `[<adj.: cold, nippy>, <adj.: calm, collected>, <adj.: aloof, disapproving>, <adj.: excellent>, <verb: chill>, <verb: take a break; abate>]`

Is there a word/term that describes the string of characters that is a set of 'words'/elements of speech?

I'm trying to name a Python object/class.

Or is "cool" just a word and that word has several definitions?

If homonyms are two words that are spelled the same and sound the same but have different meanings, "cool" must be the *spelling* that represents the set of words.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "word".

Comment: If homonyms are two words that are spelled the same and sound the same but have different meanings, "cool" must be the *spelling* that represents the set of words.

Comment: Spellings are arbitrary, like proper names, and don't represent anything. Words are sequences of phonemes, consisting of at least one morpheme each.

Comment: So, then, are cool as in cold and cool as in calm the same word, or are they different meanings of the same word, or are they different instances of the same word?

Comment: This is more of a linguistic question than a question about the English language specifically, so maybe you should ask on [linguistics.se]